# Cable joins on wiring LEDS in parallel

Tags: led, cables

So I am a newbie.

I want to wire up a bunch of LEDS in parallel, and I have it all working fine on a bread board.

I can find loads of nice drawing of the schematics
But what I cant find a good example of is how to attach LED/Resistors to the wires.
I have seen wire nuts and people just removing the insulation on the wire and soldering on to the bare wire, and then not covering it up. All these just smell bad.

What would is considered best practice.

The project is about a square meter in size.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board

Comment: This will be a meter square project, circuit board would be too small

Comment: solder + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-shrink_tubing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is solder the LED to the resistor with the bare wire obviously as you mentioned but cover it up with heat-shrink tubing insulation material.  This is the best way to avoid short circuit connections.  Note that it may be time consuming to actually have to do this for a meter square of LED connections.  Here is an example below of what I am talking about:

[image]

You would have to place the heat-shrinking element before you solder your LED to your resistor and when the solder connection is done, move the heat-shrink tube down over the solder joint.  Using a solder iron or a lighter, you can shrink the tubing material very easily and make it stick to the solder joint.  That way your circuit will be protected from potential short circuits and no LED will go bad.

Be careful to not place the solder iron or the lighter over the same place for too long since it might cause the solder joint to melt and detach itself.

Comment: EEK... if you are planning on doing a lot of those.... go buy a heat gun from your local hardware store... You will find them in the paint department. Using a soldering iron doesn't do a very even job and the flame method is ok in a pinch, but not for doing 100s of them.

Comment: Standard heat guns can get hot enough to melt the solder. A hair dryer is safer, cheaper and most houses already have one.

Comment: I find that a good lighter works fine. Just dont't overheat any one spot, you can melt solder with a lighter (I seem to recall having used that to my advantage once). And don't hold the lighter too close, or your heat shrink will get soot on it. Admittedly, the use of a lighter to do anything besides lighting up cigarettes has an aura of "crazy russian hacker" to it, but in fact it's like any other tool: If you know how to use it, it gets the job done.

Comment: There are multiple ways to shrink the tubing material.  A lighter will work fine as well as a heat gun.  Obviously you do not want to sit on the same spot with your lighter, solder iron, or heat gun for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these PC boards from RadioShack; https://www.radioshack.com/collections/breadboards-ic-sockets

You can also get a breadboard which has the same layout as the PC board making this a simple transfer.

Answer (score 0):

There are sockets for LEDS, such as the one shown below. Digi-Key part no 
[2914-ND](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/jkl-components-corp/2914/2914-ND/1552809)
[image]

However, that will get VERY expensive if your board is a meter square.

You would be much better to break up the board into a number of smaller, identical, panels make from perf-board or a PCB, that interlock together, like "Leggo" using a suitable inter-board connector.

**On another note:**

You do not mention the spacing between LEDs. I have the feeling that you intend to have hundreds if not thousands of LEDs in this panel. If so you are going to have current and power issues.

Normally, arrays of LEDs are not driven all at once, but rather they are driven as a matrix. Each row is turned on individually in sequence under the control of a sequencing circuit. This all happens fast enough that the human eye can not tell the difference.

Sometimes the individual LEDS are also augmented with a small capacitor in parallel to keep the LED turned on for a short period after the row is "scanned" so they work more like a phosphor TV.

Either way, the module method helps with power distribution too. You could even have each module have it's own, inbuilt power convertor.